# use a non-entity class as a result class for native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

every example/tutorials on the net deals with entity classes, when it comes to stored procedures (functions), where the SP collects data only from this entity. While it is quite common, that we have a complex query involving multiple tables and we want to have back some columns. For this we have can use a function in postgresql with or without any parameters.

I have this piece of code for calling such a function:

```
@Component
public class CapPlanningItemPerCapGroupImpl implements CapPlanningItemPerCapGroupRepository {
    private final EntityManager em;

    public CapPlanningItemPerCapGroupImpl(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup> getCapPlanningItems(Long companyId, Long plantId, int year, Long costAccTypeId) {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        NativeQuery<CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup> query = session.createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM get_cap_planning_items(:year, :companyId, :plantId, :costAccTypeId)", CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup.class);
        query.setParameter("year", year);
        query.setParameter("companyId", companyId);
        query.setParameter("plantId", plantId);
        query.setParameter("costAccTypeId", costAccTypeId);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

The `CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup` class isn't annotated with `@Entity`, since I don't want to store it as a datatable in the db. It's like a custom type. But with this setting, the above query fails, saying, that `CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup` is an unknown entity.

If I remove this `CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup.class` from the query call, I get the result in postman, but of course without any field names, just the raw data.

So, my question is: do I really need to convert the result list manually to the appr. class type, or is there any mapping automatism out of the box, where I don't have to list all the returned column names and types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `@SqlResultSetMapping` to describe a constructor call that Hibernate will perform for every record in the result set. I explain that in detail in [Result Set Mapping: Constructor Result Mappings](https://thorben-janssen.com/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/) on my blog.

The general idea is simple:

Your `CapPlanningItemPerCapGroup` requires a constructor that sets all attributes.

In the `@SqlResultSetMapping`, you describe the constructor call by referencing the class and listing the columns in your result set in the order in which you want to provide them to the constructor, e.g.:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "BookValueMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = BookValue.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "version", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "authorName")}))
```

After you defined your mapping, you can provide its name as the 2nd parameter to the `createNativeQuery` method.

```
List<BookValue> results = this.em.createNativeQuery("SELECT b.id, b.title, b.version, a.firstName || a.lastName as authorName FROM Book b JOIN Author a ON b.author_id = a.id", "BookValueMapping").getResultList();
```

Comment: Well, that was exactly, what I wanted to avoid (to list all the columns again). Another issue is, that I can only use `SqlResultSetMapping` on an entity, but not on a simple POJO or other class. But if this is the way, how JPA/Spring in this manner works, I have to accept it. One more question: how is it made in big software projects, where there should be a lot of stored procedured with custom results (which are not an entity and therefore not a table in the db)? This mappings should stored somewhere. I have read about xml file, is this a kind of best practice?

Comment: You can define the mapping in an XML file or add the annotation to one of your entity classes. Both options create some maintainability issues. Most teams use the annotation-based mapping.

If you don't want to specify the constructor parameters, you can use a hibernate-specific [AliasToBeanResultTransformer](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/#AliasToBeanResultTransformer).